# How to have an xml root element in python having only an opening tag and no closing tag? i.e <root/> only

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

This is what I have tried so far.

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.cElementTree import Element
import os
def write_xml_file(self):
    print os.path.isfile("/home/User_1/Project_Python/Scheduler.xml"),"The file exists ."
    root = Element("backup ")
    tree = ElementTree(root)
    sub_element_1 = Element("first", item_status="1", cur_rec="")
    root.append(sub_element_1)
    sub_element_2 = Element("second", item_recno='2', bksetname=Scheduler.xml_dict['bksetname'], backup_start_time=Scheduler.xml_dict['backup_start_time'],
                            freq=Scheduler.xml_dict['freq'], email=Scheduler.xml_dict['email'])
    root.append(sub_element_2)
    tree.write(open("Scheduler.xml", "w+"))
```

Sceduler.xml file output:

```
<backup >
    <first cur_rec="" item_status="1" />
    <second backup_start_time="2015-12-08 17:00:09.112524"   bksetname="Default_BackupSet_Admin" email="" freq="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" item_recno="2" />
</backup >
```

I want to have only a single tag as root for my Scheduler.xml file i.e. How can I do this?

Comment: could you be more precise. Provide sample output

Comment: @Vighnesh I have shared my Scheduler.xml files sample output in the question. What I am asking precisely is that in sample output of Scheduler.xml file has <backup> ...........</backup> as the root tags in the file. I want to have a root element like <backup/> (.i.e. a single tag only.)

Comment: Juna you are asking for only root tag with no sub elements `tree = ElementTree(root)` does that after which you can directly do `tree.write(open("Scheduler.xml", "w+"))` but what is the use case

Comment: @vighnesh I mean to say <backup> .... </backup> is a pair of opening and closing root tags.  I want to have a  root tag that is opening and closing in a single tag like <backup/> and ahead of that I can have the children  tags...

Comment: so where should `first and second` should come. What you are asking is illegal in XML could be more precise. See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) for understanding the base structure of XML.

Comment: To be more precise there should be only one root tag and every thing should be within that root tag. Even there should be nothing outside the root tag except prolog

Comment: ok thanks for sharing the details @vighnesh

Comment: Happy to help are you clear of what I am trying to say.